# Question on proof that matrix algebra over given algebra is semisimple iff original algebra is semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings

Let $A$ be a [finite-dimensional linear associative algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) over some field $F$. Then denote by $M_n(A)$ the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $A$ and the usual operations. Then $M_n(A)$ itself is a linear associative algebra over $F$.
I have a question on a proof that $M_n(A)$ is semisimple if and only if $A$ is semisimple. The proof uses the fact that $M_n(A)$  may be regarded as the direct product $M_n(F) \times A$, surely when I accept this fact then the result follows, but I do not see in what way $M_n(A)$ corresponds to $M_n(F) \times A$?

This claim is taken from [W.D. Munn, On semigroup algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/div-classtitleon-semigroup-algebrasdiv/34FB3666F5DE6E31BEB9F686DA041E07), and it is Lemma 4.5 in this article.

Comment: It means tensor product, not direct product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do a proof by example as I'm too lazy to write it down in general, but you'll get the idea.

Consider the map $$M_2(A)\rightarrow M_2(F)\otimes A: \begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}\otimes a + \begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}\otimes b+\dots $$

This is your desired isomorphism.

More generally you can see that semisimplicity is a Morita invariant and $A$ and $M_n(A)$ are Morita equivalent algebras.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I am not that familiar with the tensor product, so may I ask how it behaves with respect to semisimplicity in a way that yield the states proposition above? I read that you cannot always transfer these properties here in the sense that it is semisimple if the factors are, see https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/tensor-product-of-simple-algebras-need-not-be-simple-2/ or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22707/if-a-tensor-product-of-modules-is-semi-simple-are-the-tensor-factors-semi-simpl

Comment: I think you are confusing things that are not very related.

Let me explain it the way I view this issue. Let $A$ and $B$ be algebras, we call $A$ and $B$ Morita equivalent if the category of $A$-modules is equivalent to the category of $B$-modules. Then it is immediately clear that semisimplicity is a Morita invariant. The prototype example of Morita-equivalent algebras is an algebra $A$ and the algebra $M_n(A)$. (You can also compare directly the module categories and figure out that they are too different). This prototype example happens to use a tensor product, but that's not important.

Comment: It is true that semisimplicity is not preserved under tensor products. Indeed, let $A$ and $B$ be semisimple algebra then $A\otimes B$ need not be semisimple. Also the converse is false is general. This is a different question and has little to do with Morita theory, which is the subject of your question.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I learned something. But I also want to understand the argument given in the article, which just mentions the tensor product as an argument? Do you have access to it (otherwise I can copy the argument here), for does it also follow direct from the tensor product argument?

Comment: I think you should ask that question as a new question on this site. (sorry for the late response, I've been travelling the last two weeks and forgot about your response) Also, I can't view the article, so it's best to include the argument.